# How can I version automatically when a new proxy facet is deployed?

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts

We have a protocol written in Solidity, and using the *Diamond Proxy Pattern*, specifically the version by SolidState.
We have a working deployed version on mainnet, and we already did some upgrades to a few facets.

The problem is that in order to keep track of all the versions that we had deployed, i've implemented a "FacetName_Vx", where the old facet/contracts get the version name and the new facet keeps the original "FacetName".
This was implemented so we don't break the backend code when fetching the ABI and builds for local testing, but is a real pain to change the name of each contract manually and then have to go trough all the parts of the code where its also used, like in the unit tests.

Is there a way or plugin to automatically version the old smart contract and keep the codebase tidy while still keeping the rest of the stack working?

My other choice would be creating a script that does it and changes all the references on my repo, but that is not ideal, since i would need to change the script every time i add a reference.